# How i solving memory leak problem?

Tags: iphone

i developing an application in which i found memory leak in following method how i remove leak?

```
- (id)initWithString:(NSString *)str attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes
{

    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        _buffer = [str mutableCopy];
        _attributes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[ZAttributeRun attributeRunWithIndex:0 attributes:attributes], nil];
    }

    return self;

}
```

I founding leak near this line "**_buffer = [str mutableCopy]**;"

In allocation stack trace i finding simultaneous memory allocation increasing as a CFString.

Thanks.

Comment: Please take better care to format your code. A little effort on your part helps us to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will not have a memory leak if you put a line `[_buffer release]` in `dealloc` method. You have an allocation because for every methods that contains stuff like `alloc`, `retain` and `copy`... you create a new object instance. And that's ok in this case.

Another thing you have to worry is a memory crash of `_attributes` object. You own an autoreleased object and the next time you try to use it, it may be deallocated already

Answer (score 1):

mutableCopy retains the returned object, so it is your responsibility to release it when you're done with it. This is in line with the [Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html).